# Django ReportLab

Tags: django, reportlab

Buenas tengo la siguiente duda estoy realizando una función para retornar un pdf con una gráfica lo estoy haciendo con ReportLab mi duda es la siguiente como le indico al canvas que pinte mi gráfica y la retorne en el pdf generado actualmente me devuelve el pdf en blanco aca dejo mi código

```
response            = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
nombre_pdf          = oficina + piso
nombre_pdf          = get_valid_filename(nombre_pdf)
response['Content-Disposition']         = 'attachment; filename=' + nombre_pdf
```

buffer = BytesIO()
    p = canvas.Canvas(buffer)

```
from reportlab.lib.colors import PCMYKColor
from reportlab.graphics.shapes import Drawing
from reportlab.graphics.charts.barcharts import VerticalBarChart

d = Drawing(280, 250)
bar = VerticalBarChart()
bar.x = 50
bar.y = 85
data = [[1,2,3,None,None,None,5],
        [10,5,2,6,8,3,5],
        [5,7,2,8,8,2,5],
        [2,10,2,1,8,9,5],
        ]
bar.data = data
bar.categoryAxis.categoryNames = ['Year1', 'Year2', 'Year3',
                                  'Year4', 'Year5', 'Year6',
                                  'Year7']

bar.bars[0].fillColor   = PCMYKColor(0,100,100,40,alpha=85)
bar.bars[1].fillColor   = PCMYKColor(23,51,0,4,alpha=85)
bar.bars.fillColor       = PCMYKColor(100,0,90,50,alpha=85)

d.add(bar, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

bueno la verdad no se como utilizas el código como tal para generar el pdf, pero existe algo llamado wrap(parámetro1, parámetro2) que recibe dos parámetros el ancho y el alto respectivamente, estos parámetros son los que definen el espacio en el que se pintara la gráfica en el documento, después se coloca el metodo drawOn(canvas, Parámetro1, Parámetro2) este ultimo es el que pinta el gráfico, recibe el canvas, la posición en **x**, y la posición en **y** con eso bastaria para que te muestre el gráfico...

espero te sirva mi respuesta y también espero haber acertado en cuestión de la manera en que utilizas reportlab... saludos...

Comment: Hola Felipe, si bien tu respuesta puede ser una solución correcta te invito a que leas [answer] para que sepas como se debe responder correctamente, un buen ejemplo con varias líneas de código caerían muy bien para mayor entendimiento del OP, saludos !

Comment: no es sabe responder, ejemplos no se podría dar sin no tengo el método o función completa que utiliza para crear el pdf ademas, explique bien lo único que veo que le falta:

- bar.wrap(2 * cm, 2 * cm)
- bar.drawOn(canvas, 1 * cm, 1 * cm) en el caso que utilice medidas en centímetros

Comment: Tienes razón, te invito también a que te hagas el [tour] para que obtengas tu primer medalla, saludos !